# Como se configura Clion para trabajar con SDL

Tags: c++, ide

Estoy aprendiendo a usar SDL en C++ en codeblocks pero decidí usar Clion, el IDE de Jetbrains, busque como podia configurarlo pero no funciono.

Si logro llamar las librerias pero al compilar me manda este error.

Alguien sabe como podria confogurarlo de la manera correcta

[image: Este es mi archivo CMakeLists.txt]

Este es mi archivo de configuración, asi es como lo vi en un post, pero no funciona

Comment: El problema no parece que tenga que ver con Clion, sino más bien con CMake y SDL2. Acá hay una respuesta (seleccionada) que puede ayudarte: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28395833/4743711

Comment: Pero si encuentra las librerias, con eso no hay ningun error, lo que pasa es que al momento de compilar, me manda un error muy extraño que se ve en la captura.

Comment: Prueba: intenta poniendo sólo SDL2main y SDL2_test, que puede suceder que "-l" esté agregando la partícula "lib" por las suyas.

Comment: ya lo corregi, pero ahora en la consola solo aparece este mensaje al 'compilar' Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135) o solo lo que esta dentro del parentesis, con esto me podrias ayudar?